# Backpack CRUD Controller: show fields depending on model is editing

Tags: laravel, laravel-backpack

Can I setup CRUD Controller in the way to show fields depending on model is editing?

Example: I have model with fields: `id`, `type`, `field1`, `field2`.

For models with `type=type1` I want to show only `field1`:

```
$this->crud->addFields([
    ['name' => 'field1', 'label' => 'field1 label']
]);
```

for models with `type=type2` only `field2`:

```
$this->crud->addFields([
    ['name' => 'field2', 'label' => 'field2 label']
]);
```

for models with `type=type3` both `field1` and `field2`:

```
$this->crud->addFields([
    ['name' => 'field1', 'label' => 'field1 label'],
    ['name' => 'field2', 'label' => 'field2 label']
]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the very bottom of [this page in the docs](https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/3.4/crud-fields#creating-a-custom-field-type) it lists:

> Inside your custom field type, you can use these variables:
>
> ...
>
> $entry - in the Update operation, the current entry being modified (the actual values);

One way to achieve this would be to use custom fields and leverage that `$entry` variable. For example, you could make 2 custom fields like this:

**field1.blade.php**

```
@if(in_array($entry->type, ['type1','type3']))
    {{--  your field content here, see resources/views/vendor/backpack/crud/fields/text.blade.php as an example --}}
@endif
```

**field2.blade.php**

```
@if(in_array($entry->type, ['type2','type3']))
    {{--  you can even pull in the content of an existing field like this  --}}
    @include('crud::fields.text')
@endif
```

Then, in your controller, you'd always add both fields and let the fields themselves do the work of hiding the proper ones.

```
 $this->crud->addFields([
        [
            'name' => 'field1', 
            'label' => 'field1 label',
            'type'  => 'field1',
        ],
        [
            'name' => 'field2', 
            'label' => 'field2 label',
            'type'  => 'field2',
        ]
    ]);
```